# Error : file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found after set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10, grubrescue

I have a duel booted laptop (windows ,ubuntu ) and ubuntu partition is only 100gb(total 1tb hard disk). Yesterday when I started ubuntu , there is an error message "0mb disk space" . Then I examine hard disk and found there's 64.5gb log files.  I deleted those files using $ cd/var/log        rm -r /*  after that I restarted my computer and there is only this massage shown there.    Error : file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found . Grub rescue >      . I try these commands. 1.ls   2.ls (hd0,msdos6)/    3. Set root = (hd0,msdos6)  5. Set prefix= (hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub                   and then same error message occurred again. Help me to fix this

Comment: You didn't delete just log files, but deleted files (recursive) starting in / with any name (\*).  In effect you deleted your system - What backups do you have (you have loads of space ready for them; which is your fastest fix).  The `cd` command you gave didn't matter, as you specified a /\* (root directory for all files to be recursively deleted..)

Answer (score 3):

You deleted everything. That is what /* does, specifies to delete all in root folder

I sincerely hope you made a backup, because you'll need to reinstall

For future advice, to delete a folder you use

```
rm -r /folder/path
```